# What is the difference between Try/Catch and Objects.requireNonNull for NullPointerException?

Tags: java

```
try {
    switch ((Integer) navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry().getSavedStateHandle().get("position")) {
        case 1:
            //...
            break;
        case 2:
            //...
            break;
    }
} catch (NullPointerException ignored) {

}
```

I put the code inside `try/catch` but still get `NullPointerException` warning, But this method `Objects.requireNonNull(...)` will hide the warning but I'm asking myself what is the difference between `try/catch` and `Objects.requireNonNull(...)`? Also why `try/catch` not hide the warning?

[image]

Comment: They serve entirely different purposes: `Objects.requireNonNull` throws a NPE if the argument is null; try/catch handles an exception that has been thrown.

Comment: BTW, it is *almost never* the right thing to catch a `NullPointerException`, because you can avoid it by checking if the thing is null, i.e. `if (thing != null) { ... }`.

Comment: **Warning**: you are *swallowing* exceptions (i.e. having an empty `catch` clause). **Never** do that, especially not for `NullPointerException`s. Swallowing such an exception hides the true cause of an object being `null`. You should instead throw it and not catch it, so the program crashes immediately instead of silently continuing in an unknown state. `Objects::requireNonNull` does that. Otherwise, if you *expect* that certain variable is `null`, then add a null-check, as Andy already mentioned.

Comment: That warning is your IDE telling you that your code has a potential bug, and you should fix that by guarding against it. Adding a try-catch doesn't fix the potential issue, and - even worse - the try-catch you wrote will hide the problem which might be a worse bug than the one the warning is about.

Comment: Thank you guys for the clarification